# Reference request for beginner in SAS

Tags: self-study, references, sas, computational-statistics

I am interested to start learning to use SAS, I have used R for some time but for me SAS is a novelty. I do not seek any material in particular, since I'm now beginning to take the first steps with this program. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Not a reference, but you may be interested in some of the [software support links](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793) we maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked the [Ron Cody](http://support.sas.com/publishing/authors/cody.html) books (especially Applied Statistics and the SAS Programming Language), and [The Little SAS Book](https://www.sas.com/store/prodBK_65423_en.html). SAS' own documentation is pretty good too. Here's an example for [linear regression](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_gettingstarted01.htm).

Comment: We use The Little SAS Book and Ron Cody's SAS Statistics by Example as Textbooks when I learned SAS programming. Both are classic.

Answer (score 1):

I have read some parts of **SAS Statistics by Example** and that is amazing. It is written by Ron Cody. Here is the link on Google books [SAS Statistics by Example](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Wbv52vU4aLgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=learning+sas+with+examples&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w0qWVb2bK8z6Uuq8h8gO&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=learning%20sas%20with%20examples&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

There is a book, [SAS and R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466584491), that gives examples of doing the same thing in SAS and in R; I've never read the book, but [the blog](http://sas-and-r.blogspot.com/) has a ton of great examples.

Comment: Please move this answer to comment.